# Chart.js time scale axis showing large numbers instead of dates

Tags: javascript, chart.js, axis-labels, timeline, luxon

I'm trying to create a google sheets web app that'll read the data from the spreadsheet to generate this chart, which is why I am using vanilla JS.

```js
function getEventEntries() {
  function createChart(args) {
    const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
    const cfg = {
      type: 'scatter',
      data: {
        datasets: [{
          label: 'Events',
          data: args
         }],
         options: {
          scales: {
            x: { type: 'time' },
            y: { type: 'linear' }
          }
        }
      }
    };
    
    const myChart = new Chart(ctx, cfg);
  }
  
  //get data from google sheets
  //google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createChart).getEntries();
  
  // dummy data tests to figure out what formats will work
  var events = [{x: '2021-11-06 23:39:30', y: -3}, {x: '2008-04-12 13:30:14', y: 10}];
  var events1 = [{x: new Date('2021-11-06'), y: -3}, {x: new Date('2008-04-12'), y: 10}]; // actually plots data and creates an x-axis that isn't 0 to 1--still not showing date values for ticks tho
  
  createChart(events1);
}

function onLoad() {
  getEventEntries();
}

$(document).ready(onLoad);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@4.2.1/dist/chart.umd.min.js"></script>
<!-- I've tried date-fns and moment.js adapters with no luck either -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@3.3.0/build/global/luxon.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-luxon@1.3.1"></script>

 <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

As you can see when you run my snippet, the x-axis doesn't list dates in any format. It's just large numbers. I'd like to get it to list readable dates, maybe MMM YYYY format.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the `latest` version of `Chart.js`, you will need to pass the correct `configuration` object so that it can render the `dates` as per the `format` provided. Can you please try something like this:

```
 const cfg = 
  {
    type: 'scatter',
    data: {
      datasets: [
        {
          labels: "Events",          
          data: args,
        }
      ]
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        x: [ {
            display: true,
            type: 'time',
            time: {
              parser: 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm',
              tooltipFormat: 'll HH:mm',
              unit: 'day',
              unitStepSize: 1,
              displayFormats: {
                'day': 'MM/DD/YYYY'
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        y: [
          // etc...
        ],
      }
    }
  }
);
```

**UPDATE**

For older versions `2.x` of `Chart.js`, the time scale requires both a `date library and corresponding adapter` to be present. By default, Chart.js includes an adapter for `Moment.js`. More info [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/axes/cartesian/time.html).

Reference doc: [Time Axis Specific Options](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html)

Hope that helps!

**WORKING SOLUTION** (`Using Adapter`)

Hello, I figured this out. In the last version `4.2.1` of `Chartjs` it is mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#date-adapters) that

> Date Adapters
> The time scale requires both a date library and a corresponding adapter to be present.

Hence you would need to modify your code as follows:

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

**JavaScript**

In addition to loading the `Chart.js` script, you would also need to load the corresponding adapter scripts `date_fns.js` and `chartjs-adapter-date-fns-bundle.min.js`

```
const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Entries',
      data: [{
        x: '2021-11-06 23:39:30',
        y: 5
      }, {
        x: '2008-04-12 13:30:14',
        y: 10
      }],
      borderColor: 'pink'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        type: 'time'
      }
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

Here is the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kqsn4L1d/1/) for reference.

List of adapters can be found over [here](https://github.com/chartjs/awesome#adapters).

Comment: I am using the latest version of Chart.js (v.4.2.1 atm). How frustrating is it that their getting started docs still claim that users still need to choose and provide an adapter? See https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html. Anyways, this configuration object didn't change the end result unfortunately. Here's the codepen: https://codepen.io/seejessicacode/pen/QWZdELj

Comment: That's awesome that you got a working example! Can you explain why you used date-fns instead of luxon which is what I use in the code snippet provided in my question and in my codepen linked in the above comment? As you can see I was already providing a date library and corresponding adapter, so I'm not learning what I am doing wrong or missing here. Your jsfiddle works as it is but when I copy it and it's resources verbatim to codepen.io... it doesn't work. https://codepen.io/seejessicacode/pen/xxygNNL This is not your problem to fix but I wanted to explain why your answer doesn't answer my ?

Comment: Could this have to do w/ Chart.js v4+ being an ESM only package? https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/migration/v4-migration.html#general Google App Script doesn't support modules iirc so maybe all this is moot.

Comment: @Jesslyn: this is really strange. Your codepen should also work the same way. Yes may be the ESM only might be the problem. Let's try to work on this more. Can you please give more details regarding your environment? What server are you using? Hosting platform? Framework etc? I will try to mimic the same at my end and help you resolve this issue. Btw I used `date-fns` since it suited my project requirements. It's more of a personal choice.

Comment: I was originally just doing this in a web page bound to a google app script and spreadsheet. Here's a tutorial for setup: https://youtu.be/L3vqNtSBaTo But since I've been running into issues, I duplicated the issue on CodePen.io, linked above in first comment. There is no other environment details to give other than my browser is Google Chrome Version 112.0.5615.138 (Official Build) (64-bit).